# Odds of hitting a circle of a given radius from a given distance

Tags: geometry, statistics

Suppose we have a point in 2D space, and a circle with radius $R$ a distance $D$ from the point. If someone was to move out from the point at an arbitrary, uniformly distributed, angle in a straight line forever, what are the odds, as a function of $R$ and $D$, the path chosen would intersect with the circle? I got an equation through geometric construction, but I'm not sure it's accurate.

$P(R,D)={R\over{\pi D}}$

I created the image attached to illustrate my thoughts. The red circle represents the point, and the blue circle represents the circle.

Preferably, I'd like a solution that generalizes to 3D and potentially non-circular objects.

[image]

Comment: Is the angle a uniform random variable?

Comment: @D.B. yes, I forgot to include that.

Comment: It looks like the result you came up with is an approximation.Your approximation should be reasonably accurate as long as $D>>R$.

Comment: @D.B. it made sense in concept, but when I plugged in values such as $R=D$ or $R>\pi D$ I got some doubts.

Comment: The idea, which I think you understand, is that the exact probability will be the ratio of the angle range where the rays emanating from the point contact the circle with radius $r$ to the total angle range, which is $2\pi$.

Comment: @D.B. my answer is gotten by both the area and circumference ratios

Comment: A more accurate equation for $P(R,D)$ would be $\frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{R}{D})}{\pi}$

Comment: No.  Because in constructing the right triangle, the hypotenuse is $D+R$, not just $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rays that just contact either side of the small circle will be tangent to the small circle.  The angle between these two rays will be $2*\sin^{-1}(\frac{R}{R+D})$, using Pythagorean Theorem.  So, the probability is given by $P(R,D) = \frac{\sin^{-1}(\frac{R}{R+D})}{\pi}$.

Comment: In testing the function seems to increase as $D$ increases, which doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: No.  If $D>>R$, the probability actually approaches $0$, which does make sense.

Comment: You're right. Any ideas for generalizing into n-D or other shapes?

Comment: I think it's basically this same process for other shapes in 2-D.  You just need to do a similar geometry analysis.  If you're looking in 3-D.  you might ask the probability of a ray emanating from a point hitting a ball distance $R+D$ away.  In this case, you could first calculate the angle ranges for $\pi$ and $\theta$ in spherical coordinates, fix a radius $\rho$, and calculate the ratio of the circular cut-out of the shpere of radius $\rho$ to the total surface area, which would be $4*\pi*\rho^2$.